# "dnf install vidalia" on Fedora Core 24?

Tags: dnf, tor

I'm in the process of installing a (somewhat modified) Fedora Core 24 system, and am still trying to do things in the mostly right way.

How can I get `dnf install vidalia` (which, in quotes, has only Spanish results in google) to work?

I've seen RPM files for vidalia, but I'd prefer to add a new repo (like pkgs.org?) instead of grabbing the rpm file directly? I also want to get whatever version is presumably the "best" for Fedora Core 24.

I did `dnf install tor`, but `rpm -ql tor` (and `dnf provides '*/vidalia'`) shows that tor doesn't include vidalia and neither does any repo I have currently installed.

I do know how to add new repos and have done this earlier:

```
sudo dnf install --allowerasing --best http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm`
```

so I guess I'm looking for the magic command similar to the above that installs a repo that allows me to install vidalia properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid *vidalia* appears to be retired: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/vidalia/  Probably, there isn't any repository available for F24 that contains it.  If there is you have to find it first, there is no magic command for that part.

(By the way, the name was changed from *Fedora Core* to just *Fedora* a long time ago.)

Comment: That's really disappointing-- vidalia was one the few useful GUIs. Just to clarify for others, torproject.org itself has discontinued this, not just Fedora: https://dist.torproject.org/vidalia/ -- oh, and to defend my honor, I'd like to point out `dnf list | fgrep fc24 | wc -l` yields 51953, so it's still "really" Fedora Core :)

Answer (score 1):

I used https://software.opensuse.org/422/en for years to get packages for Fedora.

This example is for Vidalia in Fedora 25

https://software.opensuse.org/package/vidalia

In this case you can select the 64 bit Tumbleweed:
Open with Software Install and Launch!

As a general rule you should download source first and LOOK very carefully over dependencies and install in Fedora.  In this case QT is there so it is not necessary!

I switched from Fedora about a year ago because to much work for free (debug their system).

A lot of OpenSuse RPM work in Fedora!  Next time just search!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great answer, but, poking around a little I found:

`dnf install tor-arm-gui tor-arm`

installs "arm", a vt100 "GUI" that lets you look at your tor configuration and connections in real time.

It seems really poorly developed and has a messy interface (and doesn't appear to understand vt100 well), so I really wouldn't recommend it, but it is there.